# How to make axis the same scale/ size?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This what I have:

```
x = df2['bulk_TPM']
y = df2['scRNA_TPM']
plt.scatter(x,y,cmap ='summer',
        edgecolor='black',linewidth=1, alpha = 0.75)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.title('bulk vs scRNA log10 TPM')
plt.xlabel('bulk_TPM')
plt.ylabel('scRNA_TPM')
```

I attempted changing the scale by doing this:

```
plt.xscale('log').xlim(0,10**5)
```

and same method for y-axis but
get weird scale size.

I would like both x and y axis to have same 0-10^5, how can I resolve this[image]

Comment: try plt.yticks(np.arange(min, max, step)) ?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html) describes this solution which I expect to work in your case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Plot circle of radius 3.

an = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axs[0, 0].plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an))
axs[0, 0].set_title('not equal, looks like ellipse', fontsize=10)

axs[0, 1].plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an))
axs[0, 1].axis('equal')
axs[0, 1].set_title('equal, looks like circle', fontsize=10)

axs[1, 0].plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an))
axs[1, 0].axis('equal')
axs[1, 0].set(xlim=(-3, 3), ylim=(-3, 3))
axs[1, 0].set_title('still a circle, even after changing limits', fontsize=10)

axs[1, 1].plot(3 * np.cos(an), 3 * np.sin(an))
axs[1, 1].set_aspect('equal', 'box')
axs[1, 1].set_title('still a circle, auto-adjusted data limits', fontsize=10)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]